# Black screen appears in console in Swing application after upgrading 1.7 to 1.8u51

Tags: java, swing, console, java-8

I am running a Java Swing application which is the presentation tier, business tier is Hessian Protocol exposing stateless session EJBs and backend tier is Sybase. I am getting a strange behavior as I am getting a black screen after launching my Swing application and clicking a button. I have upgraded my Java version from 1.7 to 1.8u51 and application server used is WildFly 8.2.0.

Swing application after launching if I click any button or icon, it gets hanged and black screen appears on the Java console. The issue is not occurring with 1.7 and it is only with 1.8u51 version.

Once I click the expand button, the table is shown in a different position. Is this something related to change in positioning of JTable in JDK 8 ? Please help me if any ideas.

Have anyone faced this strange behavior?

Comment: The remote request ends, you have the full response?

Comment: am getting full response .. Daniel.

Comment: This button does something specific ?

Comment: It is a expand / collapse button showing a foldable table made using JTable.

Comment: Once I click the expand button, the table is shown in a different position. Is this something related to change in positioning of JTable in JDK 8 ? Please help me if any ideas.

Comment: is Java Fx causing a problem ? Can anybody help as this seems to be an odd issue